# Matrices in the plane,polygon assignment, help. please?

Tags: calculus, matrices, polygons

a.) Given polygon P with vertices (1,5), (4,8), (8,5), (6,2) and (2,1), find the following:

Find the area of P.

Tip: Make sure to move COUNTERCLOCKWISE from point to point to ensure you get a positive area.

b.) Find the vertices P' after reflection P over the x-axis.

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Not sure where matrices come in, but it looks like you can just use the Shoelace formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) for (a)

Answer (score 0):

1) well there's a nice formula for the area of a triangle with vertices $(A_1, A_2), (B_1,B_2)$ and $(C_1, C_2)$:

$Area = (1/2)  det\begin{pmatrix} B_1 - A_1 & C_1 - A_1 \\  B_2 - A_2 & C_2 - A_2 \end{pmatrix}$

and you can always split your polygon in a bunch of triangles

2) reflecting over x-axis just makes all y-coordinates change sign